# Is such a function of bounded variation?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and let $(x_n) $ be a given sequence of points such that: 
$$
a<x_{n+1} <x_n<b \textrm{ for } n\in \mathbb R, \atop
x_n \rightarrow a.
$$
Let's assume that
$$
sup_{n\in \mathbb N} var(f, [x_n,b])<\infty.
$$
Is it then $f$ of bounded variation on $[a,b]$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* If $f$ is bounded on $[a,x_n]$ for some $n$, then your condition implies that $f$ is of bounded variation on $[a,b]$. Otherwise, you can construct a sequence $y_n \searrow a$ with $f(y_{n+1}) - f(y_n) > 1$ which contradicts your condition.

Comment: Thanks. Let's assume that $f$ is bounded. Why $f$ is of bounded variation?

Comment: Then for any partition $a = t_0 < t_1 < \ldots < t_m =b$ with $t_1 < x_n$ we have $|f(a) - f(t_1)| + |f(t_1) - f(t_2)| + \ldots + |f(t_{m-1}) - f(b)| \le |f(a)| + |f(t_1)| + sup_n V_f([x_n, b])$.

Comment: Very thanks. I understand.